# Should I loot every house in Witcher 3?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I've been playing Witcher 3 for a little while now, and I find myself exploring every house in new cities that I discover. I keep thinking that this is a waste of time because I only seem to find booze and dolls, but I can't control it because I'm afraid to miss something.

My question is, should I spend the time to loot every house? Will I find some useful stuff or unlock some quests if I do so?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, if nothing else you can find vital items like Alcohest, Dwarven Spirit, food and drink without having to buy them. I don't think there are any quests to be found outside of looting things that are obviously 'treasure chests'.

Answer (score 6):

Depends what you're looking for. The chest contents are randomized, and you can pick up expensive crafting components or recipees/blueprints even in shabby village cottages. So it's not a complete waste of time.

That said, you'll get better loot looking for hidden treasure or monster nests, and I don't remember any really unique content you might miss if you skip on being a kleptomaniac.

Answer (score 3):

I'm the same way, it's that oldschool game treasure hunting mentality, it's tough to shake. Anyway, I can say that while in the base game I can't think of anything that was extraordinary in a random NPC house. As mentioned above, I can say I have never needed to craft or purchase Dwarven spirit or strong alcohol needed to replenish stocks after meditating. Also, you do come across some places that have a number of furs that can land some decent coin at the right merchants.

Now, I just started the first DLC (Hearts of Stone) and it's a whole different ball game for random treasure hunting in the areas that are newly created on the map. I find awesome weapons and armor all over the place. While this isn't so much in people's homes, it definitely is if you go off the path a little. Particularly, a light house in the far northwest corner above Novigrad, there are some random people living there and I almost didn't go in. I'm glad I did, because the all black New Moon armor is sweet and way better than what is provided during the story.

Answer (score 0):

It's rare, but sometimes you find runestones, books or crafting supplies that are useful. Most houses just have junk you'll end up selling or adding to a giant horde of stuff you don't care about until you don't have enough of it for the crafting or alchemy task.